# Finding the shortest path in a maze using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, maze

recently I've been trying to work on some recursive maze code that returns the shortest path in a maze. If there is no path through the maze, then the code would return -1.

For example, for the board:

```
W-S-
----
--X-
```

Where S is the start of the maze, W represents a wall, X represents the desired destination, and - represents an available path point.
The output would be: `2`

For the board:

```
 -SW
 -W-
 W-X
```

the output would be `-1`

This is all carried out through a board class that takes a string and the dimensions of a maze, a check function that returns the shortest path, and a win function that returns the shortest path or -1 if there is no path. However, when I run my code, I'm getting an output of negative 1 for the first example and an output of 1 for the second example.

My code:

Board Class:

```
  class Board
{
   private char[][] board;  
   private int maxPath = 9999;

   public Board(int rows, int cols, String line)  
   {
      char[][] board1 = new char[rows][cols];
      int z = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
         for(int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
            board1[x][y] = line.charAt(z);
            z++;
         }
      }
      board = board1;


   }

    /** returns the length of the longest possible path in the Board   */
   public int getMaxPath()      
   {  
      return maxPath; 
   }    

   public void display()
   {
      if(board==null) 
         return;
      System.out.println();
      for(int a = 0; a<board.length; a++)
      {
         for(int b = 0; b<board[0].length; b++)
         {
            System.out.print(board[a][b]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

   /**  
    *  calculates and returns the shortest path from S to X, if it exists   
    *  @param r is the row of "S"
    *  @param c is the column of "S"
    */
   public int check(int r, int c)
   {    
      if(r<0||r > board.length-1||c<0||c>board[0].length-1) {
         return maxPath;
      }
      if(board[r][c] == '*') {
         return maxPath;
      }
      if(board[r][c] == 'W') {
         return maxPath;
      }
      if(board[r][c] == 'X') {
         return 0;
      }
      if(board[r][c] == '-') {
         board[r][c] = '*';
      }

      int up = 1 + check(r-1,c);
      int down = 1 + check(r+1,c);
      int left = 1 + check(r,c-1);
      int right = 1 + check(r,c+1);
      board[r][c] = '-';
      if(up < down) {
         if(up < left) {
            if(up < right) {
               return up;
            }
            else {
               return right;
            }
         }
         else {
            if(left < right) {
               return left;
            }
            else {
               return right;
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         if(down < left) {
            if(down < right) {
               return down;
            }
            else {
               return right;
            }
         }
         else {
            if(left < right) {
               return left;
            }
            else {
               return right;
            }
         }
      }


   }    

   /**  
    *  precondition:  S and X exist in board
    *  postcondition:  returns either the length of the path
    *                  from S to X, or -1, if no path exists.    
    */
   public int win()
   {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      int z = 0;
      int startRow = 0;
      int startCol = 0;
      while( x < board.length && z == 0) {
         while(y < board[0].length && z == 0) {
            if(board[x][y] == 'S') {
               z++;
               startRow = x;
               startCol = y;
            }
            y++;
         }
         x++;
      }
      System.out.println(startRow + " " + startCol);
      if(check(startRow,startCol) < maxPath) {
         return check(startRow,startCol);
      }
      else if (check(startRow,startCol) == maxPath) {
         return 1;
      }
      else {
         return -1;
      }

   }
```

Test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Board b = null;
      b = new Board(3,4,"W-S-------X-"); 
      b.display();
      System.out.println("Shortest path is " + b.win());  //2

      b = new Board(4,3,"S-W-----X-W-"); 
      b.display();
      System.out.println("Shortest path is " + b.win());  //4

      b = new Board(3,4,"X-WS--W-W---"); 
      b.display();
      System.out.println("Shortest path is " + b.win());  //7

      b = new Board(3,5,"W--WW-X----SWWW"); 
      b.display();
      System.out.println("Shortest path is " + b.win());  //1

      b = new Board(3,3,"-SW-W-W-X");     //no path exists
      b.display();
      System.out.println("Shortest path is " + b.win());  //-1

      b = new Board(5,7,"-W------W-W-WX--S----W----W-W--W---");     //Example Board 1
      b.display();
      System.out.println("Shortest path is " + b.win());  //5

      b = new Board(4,4,"-WX--W-W-WW-S---");     //Example Board -1
      b.display();
      System.out.println("Shortest path is " + b.win());  //5

      //what other test cases should you test?

   }
```

Desired outputs:

```
 W-S-
 ----
 --X-
 Shortest path is 2

 S-W
 ---
 --X
 -W-
 Shortest path is 4

 X-WS
 --W-
 W---
 Shortest path is 7

 W--WW
 -X---
 -SWWW
 Shortest path is 1

 -SW
 -W-
 W-X
 Shortest path is -1

 -W-----
 -W-W-WX
 --S----
 W----W-
 W--W---
 Shortest path is 5

 -WX-
 -W-W
 -WW-
 S---
 Shortest path is -1
```

My wrong outputs:

```
W-S-
----
--X-
Shortest path is -1

S-W
---
--X
-W-
Shortest path is 1

X-WS
--W-
W---
Shortest path is -1

W--WW
-X---
-SWWW
Shortest path is -1

-SW
-W-
W-X
Shortest path is 1

-W-----
-W-W-WX
--S----
W----W-
W--W---
Shortest path is 1

-WX-
-W-W
-WW-
S---
Shortest path is 1
```

My new mostly right outputs:

```
W-S-
----
--X-
0 2
Shortest path is 2

S-W
---
--X
-W-
0 0
Shortest path is 4

X-WS
--W-
W---
0 3
Shortest path is 7

W--WW
-X---
-SWWW
0 0
Shortest path is 1

-SW
-W-
W-X
0 1
Shortest path is -1

-W-----
-W-W-WX
--S----
W----W-
W--W---
0 0
Shortest path is 9

-WX-
-W-W
-WW-
S---
0 0
Shortest path is -1
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong(just between my new outputs and the desired outputs) and how I can fix it?

EDIT: Thank you peter and mrB, I have implemented your suggestions and updated my code to fit that!

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and examine relevant values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are 2 issues with your code.

First, the while loops in your `win()` function will leave your starting position at the top left of your boards.

1. `z == 0` which means that `z > 0` is false and the while loop will not be used.
2. You don't increment `x` or `y`, so it's good that the z condition fails or you'd have infinite loops.

Second, `maxPath` is never assigned a value. Making it `0` and all results that go out of bounds (I'm thinking the first up) become the result of `check(x,y)` as it's `1 + 0`. The `-1` results are all when the top left of the board is `'W'` or `'X'` in which case `check(x,y)` returns `0` which is equal to `maxPath`

You might also want to set `check(x,y)` to a int rather than calling it again to return a result (bigger boards could become a bit resource intensive).

In summary

1. Update while loops to use `z == 0` and increment `x` and `y` respectively.
2. Set `maxPath` to a value, e.g. `9999`
3. Change condition in `win()` to check that result of `check(x,y)` is `< maxPath` (otherwise you might not get a `-1` result out of `win()` because there is a possibility that `maxPath` will be incremented by 1 or more and `!= maxPath` would result in true).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! They have helped a lot. However, I still have two issues. The first is that my return for mazes where the start and the end are adjacent is -1. The second is that for my second to last test case(the one where the desired output is 5), I end up getting 9 as my answer? Could you perhaps take a look at my check function and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've updated my question to contain my updates win() and check() code as well.

Comment: The moment `S` is on a row that is not the first row, you're starting point is `0,0`. Believe that's because of using while loops to resolve start. You can either use `for` loops or reset `y` to `0` when you increment `x`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not catch that mistake! You've been a great help!

Comment: No problem, was an interesting question and funky approach to the problem. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int right = 1 + check(r-1,c+1);
```

I strongly suspect you mean:

```
int right = 1 + check(r,c+1);
```

Comment: I don't think that this matters because in the end, its just a name. So if I cover all 4 sides, I should be fine.

Comment: my bad, i read your suggestion wrong. That has helped me somewhat.